# WP7 - Applying style to the contents of a ContentPresenter

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a `ContentPresenter` within the `ItemTemplate` for a `ListBox`. I want to apply a style to any `TextBlock`'s that it contains. I tried the following:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Margin="12,0,0,0"
                  SizeChanged="OnContentPresenterSizeChanged">
  <ContentPresenter.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" />
  </ContentPresenter.Resources>
</ContentPresenter>
```

But I'm getting a `XamlParseException` saying `Unknown attribute TargetType on element Style`. Intellisense doesn't like `x:Type`, the only things it shows in the values auto-complete for `TargetType` are the names of controls themselves. So I also tried

```
TargetType="TextBlock"
```

That didn't cause any exceptions but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Also, the TextBlocks are usually within a `StackPanel`, could that be an issue?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it works for a `ContentPresenter` but to apply a common style to all child elements, you provide a style in the container.

So I would advise you to put the style in element's resources which contains the `ContentPresenter`.

### Example:

```
<Border>
    <Border.Resources>
        <ContentPresenter.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" />
        </ContentPresenter.Resources>
    </Border.Resources>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      Margin="12,0,0,0"
                      SizeChanged="OnContentPresenterSizeChanged"></ContentPresenter>
</Border>
```

Comment: That doesn't work, it still doesn't like `x:Type`. Also, placing `ContentPresenter.Resources` outside of the `ContentPresenter` won't compile. I can get around this by setting the style on the `TextBlock` in code-behind when I create it. It'd be nice to do it in XAML though.

Answer (score -3):

You just have to use `TargetType="TextBlock"` instead.

Comment: Like I've said in the question, I tried that but it didn't work.